# Documentum error :[DM_STORAGE_E_BAD_TICKET]

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, documentum-dfs, documentum-dfc, documentum7.3

I am trying to get the content of all the documents (current version) from a documentum source using the following code

```
IDfSysObject document = (IDfSysObject) session.getObject(new DfId(eachFileMetadata.get(some document id).toString()));
ByteArrayInputStream docContent = document.getContent();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    DfException:: THREAD: Thread-708; MSG: [DM_STORAGE_E_BAD_TICKET]error:  "Use of invalid ticket for storage object with name dist_store_a_store_004; storage may be improperly configured.
Ticket was 0000000080000103.  Data Ticket was 1."; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: DfException:: THREAD: Thread-708; MSG: [DM_STORAGE_E_EXEC_FAIL]error:  "Command execution failure: mv /dctm/dm011/dmadmin/gwdmpr71/dist_store_a_store_004/0001782c/80/00/01/03* /dctm/dm011/dmadmin/gwdmpr71/dist_store_a_store_004/0001782c/80/00/01/03.doc. os_error: No Error Message Available."; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.docbase.DocbaseExceptionMapper.newException(DocbaseExceptionMapper.java:57)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.MessageEntry.getException(MessageEntry.java:39)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseMessageManager.getException(DocbaseMessageManager.java:137)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.netwise.NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.checkForMessages(NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.java:329)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.netwise.NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.applyForInt(NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.java:600)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection$6.evaluate(DocbaseConnection.java:1343)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.evaluateRpc(DocbaseConnection.java:1141)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.applyForInt(DocbaseConnection.java:1336)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.docbase.DocbaseApi.makePuller(DocbaseApi.java:630)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.RawPuller.<init>(RawPuller.java:22)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.Session.makePuller(Session.java:3756)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionHandle.makePuller(SessionHandle.java:2468)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.BlockPuller.<init>(BlockPuller.java:27)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.PusherPullerContentAccessor.buildStreamFromContext(PusherPullerContentAccessor.java:40)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.PusherPullerContentAccessor.getStream(PusherPullerContentAccessor.java:28)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentAccessorFactory.getStream(ContentAccessorFactory.java:37)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.Store.getStream(Store.java:63)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.DistributedStore___PROXY.getStream(DistributedStore___PROXY.java)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.Content.getStream(Content.java:185)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.Content___PROXY.getStream(Content___PROXY.java)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentManager.getStream(ContentManager.java:84)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentManager.getStream(ContentManager.java:53)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContentEx3(DfSysObject.java:1952)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContentEx2(DfSysObject.java:1942)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContent(DfSysObject.java:1932)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfDocument___PROXY.getContent(DfDocument___PROXY.java)

Followed by: DfException:: THREAD: Thread-708; MSG: [DM_STORAGE_E_EXEC_FAIL]error:  "Command execution failure: mv /dctm/dm011/dmadmin/gwdmpr71/dist_store_a_store_004/0001782c/80/00/01/03* /dctm/dm011/dmadmin/gwdmpr71/dist_store_a_store_004/0001782c/80/00/01/03.doc. os_error: No Error Message Available."; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.docbase.DocbaseExceptionMapper.newException(DocbaseExceptionMapper.java:57)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.MessageEntry.getException(MessageEntry.java:39)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseMessageManager.getException(DocbaseMessageManager.java:137)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.netwise.NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.checkForMessages(NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.java:329)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.netwise.NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.applyForInt(NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.java:600)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection$6.evaluate(DocbaseConnection.java:1343)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.evaluateRpc(DocbaseConnection.java:1141)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.applyForInt(DocbaseConnection.java:1336)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.docbase.DocbaseApi.makePuller(DocbaseApi.java:630)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.RawPuller.<init>(RawPuller.java:22)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.Session.makePuller(Session.java:3756)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionHandle.makePuller(SessionHandle.java:2468)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.BlockPuller.<init>(BlockPuller.java:27)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.PusherPullerContentAccessor.buildStreamFromContext(PusherPullerContentAccessor.java:40)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.PusherPullerContentAccessor.getStream(PusherPullerContentAccessor.java:28)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentAccessorFactory.getStream(ContentAccessorFactory.java:37)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.Store.getStream(Store.java:63)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.DistributedStore___PROXY.getStream(DistributedStore___PROXY.java)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.Content.getStream(Content.java:185)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.Content___PROXY.getStream(Content___PROXY.java)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentManager.getStream(ContentManager.java:84)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentManager.getStream(ContentManager.java:53)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContentEx3(DfSysObject.java:1952)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContentEx2(DfSysObject.java:1942)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContent(DfSysObject.java:1932)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfDocument___PROXY.getContent(DfDocument___PROXY.java)
```

the above error occured when I am trying to get the content of a document,can anyone please help me??

Comment: Error message is pretty much self explanatory: [DM_STORAGE_E_BAD_TICKET]error:  "Use of invalid ticket for storage object with name dist_store_a_store_004; storage may be improperly configured.

Comment: can u tell me what should I do to fix the above error??